# How to add paint to the bottom and stain/varnish to the top of a wood project?

Tags: paint, varnish

I have a small wood pencil holder that I want to paint on the bottom with blue and then stain and varnish the top.

My question is how do I go about the varnish?  Can I varnish over the paint or do I use blue tape to block off the painted portion and varnish after I've painted then remove the blue tape (which will ruin the varnish right?)?  Or do I just varnish very carefully?  Or do I paint after I varnish and possible paint over the bottom of the varnish?

Answer (score 3):

I have crossed this situation where clients want to stain their banisters and paint the spindles. In such cases, we stain first, then tape off the banister and paint the spindles.

[image]
**Note:** You can stain (light colors / not solid) over paint and it will adhere, giving it an antique look. Example photo below of stain over paint.

[image]